# Mysql database connection error

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

whenever I am trying to connect  phpMyadmin  through php script it is showing some errors like this                                                                          `Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`                                                                                           I am using ubuntu 11.04.So can you tell me how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error simply means that your connection information is incorrect.  You are trying to connect to the MySQL database using the username "www-data@localhost" with no password.  Check your MySQL permissions to  see what you need to do.  Either this login needs a password or this login is not specified as being permitted to access the data.

To check what permissions you have for that user, run this MySQL script:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE user='www-data';
```

To add rights to that user (if they are missing), run this script:

```
GRANT SELECT ON database.* TO 'www-data'@'localhost';
```

Comment: Biggs is right. also, on a dev box you can use the root usename and password u specified during mysql installation. if you are not comfortable with CLI you can install [link](http://phpmyadmin.net) for web interface. you can also use tasksel for performing various tasks like installing AMP on linux box in one go.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'www-data';
$dbpass = '<PUT PASSWORD FOR  HERE>';
$dbname = '<YOUR DATABASE NAME>';

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname);
```